# Envio de emails con nodemailer, nodejs

Tags: ajax, nodejs, nodemailer

estoy intentando enviar emails a través de nodemailer y una sencilla aplicación. De alguna forma, al intentar hacer post al servidor, parece que salta un error de conexión, pero no consigo saber que pasa exactamente. Este es el código;
router.post('/sendmail', function(req, res, next) {
...
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
       host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
        secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
        port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
        auth: {
           user: "username@outlook.com",
           pass: "password"

```
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});



// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Username \u26AD <username@server>', // sender address

     to: 'destination@server.com', // list of receivers
    subject: subject,
    text: text_content, // plaintext body
    html: html_content,
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log( info);
    res.end('Sent :)');
});
```

---

Esta es la llamada ajax a /sendMail

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/sendmail",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    owner: '56fab5a69835c6dc22b4603d',
                    name: $scope.reservation.name,
                    email: $scope.reservation.email,
                    notes: $scope.reservation.province+': ' + notes,
                    phone: $scope.reservation.phone,
                    origin: "albertotaboada.com configurador",
                    ip: ip
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    $scope.form_status = "success";
                }, error: function () {
                    $scope.form_status = "success";
                }
            });
```

---

El error que salta en el moneto de hacer POST:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587]
```

code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 587,
  stage: 'init' }

alguien puede ayudarme por favor??
un saludo¡¡

Comment: agrega esto a tu configuración: 

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});

De manera alternativa para outlook puedes usar 
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});

Comment: Hola como estas intentando agregar algo xd te dejo un link con tu mismo problema resuelto quizás te pueda servir de apoyó un saludo! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024428/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1465-nodemailer

Answer (score 0):

creo que te falto algo de configuración, agrega esto a tu configuración:

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});
```

Otra opcion seria usar [nodemailer-wellknown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-wellknown) :D

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        service: "Hotmail",
        auth: {
            user: "user@outlook.com",
            pass: "password"
        }
    });
```

Saludos